# Bootstrap typeahead

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete

I am using bootstrap typeahead for auto-complete functionality.
I need typeahead to return the result when the input gets active (on mouse-click or tab to the input), not wait for the user to type 1st character. More like a typedown.

```
<input id="input01" class="input-medium" type="text" data-provide="typeahead" placeholder="TypeAhead…" autocomplete="off">


$(document).ready(function($) {
    // Workaround for bug in mouse item selection
    $.fn.typeahead.Constructor.prototype.blur = function() {
        var that = this;
        setTimeout(function () { that.hide(); }, 250);
    };

    $('#input01').typeahead({
        source: function(query, process) {
            return ["hello","world", "awesome"];
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Bootstrp combobox](https://github.com/danielfarrell/bootstrap-combobox) worked perfectly

Answer (score 2):

I haven't worked with that plugin [in a long time](https://github.com/tcrosen/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead) but try calling the lookup (or whatever method it is now) manually.

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  var $input = $('#input01');

  $input.typeahead({
    source: function(query, process) {
      return ["hello","world", "awesome"];
    }
  });

  $input.on('focus', function() {
    $input.typeahead.lookup();
  });
});
```

Comment: function is yet lookup, but did not help.